# Remove empty values without changing the rest of the data frame in r

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this data frame (much bigger, this is an example):

```
           V1        V2   V3   V4   V5
row1                       1    2    3
row2 Row1name row1class    4    3    8
row3                      12    6    3
row4 row2name row2class    3    7    5
row5 row3name row3class <NA> <NA> <NA>
row6 row4name row4class <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

I want to fix the data so that I get the following:

```
           V1        V2   V3   V4   V5
row1 Row1name row1class    1    2    3
row2 Row2name row2class    4    3    8
row3 Row3name row3class   12    6    3
row4 Row4name row4class    3    7    5
```

Any idea how to remove the empty spaces without changing V3-V5?

Comment: Are the empty rows in V1-V2 empty strings?

Comment: Can you please `dput` a portion of your data?

Answer (score 3):

If you have same number of empty and `NA` values in each column, you can use

```
purrr::map_df(df,  ~.x[!(.x == '' | is.na(.x))])

#   V1       V2        V3    V4    V5   
#  <chr>    <chr>     <chr> <chr> <chr>
#1 Row1name row1class 1     2     3    
#2 row2name row2class 4     3     8    
#3 row3name row3class 12    6     3    
#4 row4name row4class 3     7     5
```

and similarly in base R :

```
do.call(cbind.data.frame, lapply(df, function(x) x[!(x == '' | is.na(x))]))
```

You may want to use `type.convert` after using the above to change the class of the columns to their respective classes.

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(V1 = c("", "Row1name", "", "row2name", "row3name", 
"row4name"), V2 = c("", "row1class", "", "row2class", "row3class", 
"row4class"), V3 = c("1", "4", "12", "3", NA, NA), V4 = c("2", 
"3", "6", "7", NA, NA), V5 = c("3", "8", "3", "5", NA, NA)), 
row.names = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", "row6"),
class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

The `<NA>` indicates character data where numeric is needed; transform!

```
dat[3:5] <- lapply(dat[3:5], as.numeric)
```

Now, `NA` in `rowSums` removes the `NA` rows.

```
res <- dat[!is.na(rowSums(dat[3:5])), ]
```

And rebuild the first two columns using `paste`.

```
res <- dat[!is.na(rowSums(dat[3:5])), ]
res <- transform(res, 
          V1=paste0(rownames(res), "name"),
          V2=paste0(rownames(res), "Class"))
```

### Result

```
res
#            V1        V2 V3 V4 V5
# row1 row1name row1Class  1  2  3
# row2 row2name row2Class  4  3  8
# row3 row3name row3Class 12  6  3
# row4 row4name row4Class  3  7  5
```

---

*Data*

```
dat <- structure(list(V1 = c("", "Row1name", "", "row2name", "row3name", 
"row4name"), V2 = c("", "row1class", "", "row2class", "row3class", 
"row4class"), V3 = c("1", "4", "12", "3", "<NA>", "<NA>"), V4 = c("2", 
"3", "6", "7", "<NA>", "<NA>"), V5 = c("3", "8", "3", "5", "<NA>", 
"<NA>")), row.names = c("row1", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", 
"row6"), class = "data.frame")
```